# Get values in R

Tags: r

I have an object (wordc) in R that looks like this

```
> wordc
tw.text
               aint     booking       coast         coz     getting       hello 
      6           1           1           1           1           1           1 
message      modern moderncoast       mpesa      online     payment     working 
      1           1           1           1           1           1           1
```

When I run 'typeof(wordc)' I get I get that it is an 'integer'

I can get the names with the command names(wordc)

But, how can I get the values?

I can get individual ones with wordc[[1]], but what is the command (similar to names(wordc)) to get them all?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "get them all"? what do you want to do with them? as far as I can tell you've 'got them all'

Comment: Like for example with c(wordc[[1]], wordc[[2]]) I can get 2. I want to get all of them, without having to write wordc[[x]] for each of them

Comment: `wordc` IS all the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wordc` already has all values.

In addition it has names.

To drop the names, use

```
as.vector(wordc)
```

Note: `[[` selects one element, and drops the name, too, as you already figured out.

Comment: `unname(wordc)`, too.

Comment: or setNames(wordc, NULL)